# Probability of 5 dices being 6s, given that I know 3 are 6s

Tags: probability, dice

Imagine a game with two players who each throw 5 dice and only they can see their own dice. If we roll and I see that I have 3 sixes, what are the probabilities that there are at least 5 sixes in total (all 10 dice P(X>=5))? I believe this is a cumulative binomial distribution, but I can't figure out how to calculate the conditional.

P.S. I'm not asking for the probability that the other player has 2 sixes, but the probability, given that I have 3 sixes, that there are 5 in total.

Comment: Regarding your PS, how are the two different? The dice you roll and the dice the other player rolls are independent events. Thus the probability that there are at least five sixes given that you have three should be identical to the probability your opponent has at least two sixes.

Comment: Does "I see I have 3 sixes" mean " *only* 3", or "*at least* 3" (as in, you see 3 but may have more)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If player-1 has *exactly* 3 sixes, then the only way the two players can have 5 or more sixes is if player-2 has 2 or more.  Just use binomial distribution to calculate this.

$$\Bbb P(P_2 \geq 2) = 1-\Bbb P(P_2 \leq 1)= 1 - \binom{5}{4}\frac {5^4} {6^5} - \frac {5^5} {6^5}$$

---

However, if player-1 merely sees 3 sixes but *may* have more, then you need to use conditional probability.

$$\begin{align}
 \Bbb P(P_1+P_2 \geq 5\mid P_1\geq 3) & = \frac{\Bbb P(P_1+P_2 \geq 5, P_1\geq 3)}{\Bbb P(P_1\geq 3)}
\\[2ex] & =\frac{
 (\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{1}+1)\frac {5^5}{6^{10}}
+(\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{1})\frac {5^4}{6^{10}}
+(\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{2})\frac {5^3}{6^{10}}
+(\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{3})\frac {5^2}{6^{10}}
+(\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{4})\frac {5}{6^{10}}
+\frac {1}{6^{10}}
}{\binom{5}{3}\frac {5^2}{6^5}+\binom{5}{2}\frac{5}{6^5}+ \frac{1}{6^5}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you have exactly three sixes, then the probability of at least five sixes total is

$$1 - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5 - 5 \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^4.$$

That is, one minus the probability that there are exactly three, or exactly four, fives total.